# rerender in react to get a new name everytime I refreshed?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

why this code give me infinite loop?

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './style.css';
import { faker } from '@faker-js/faker';

export default function App() {
  const data = faker.name.firstName();
  const [name, setName] = useState(data);

  useEffect(() => {
    setName(faker.name.firstName());
  }, [name]);

  return <div>{name}</div>;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-6ept5o?file=App.tsx

I want a new generated name using faker everytime i refreshed the page.

Comment: first of all you don't need the use Effect here , but to answer the infinite loop problem useEffect hook runs every time its dependency array changes and you are re assigning name inside it so it creates an infinite loop in consequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there's several problems here. Firstly, React state isn't persisted when you refresh the page. To do that you'd have to web storage or some library to help store when changing/refreshing the page. So you don't need an effect here nor to worry about getting new fake data on refresh, you will.

Also, when a functional component re-renders, the entire function gets run again. So this: `const data = faker.name.firstName();` gets run *every* time you render. If you want to use it as an initial state, use the function argument to `useState` which runs it once on page load: `useState(() => faker.name.firstName())`;

Finally, in regards to the infinite loop, your effect has `name` as a dependency, but inside it you also set name state. So you're getting a loop.

```
Component renders:
-> effect runs, setting name state
-> set state triggers re-render with new name
-> new name triggers effect, since name is a dependency
-> effects sets name state to new value
-> set state triggers re-render
```

and so on. But in this case, you don't actually need an effect at all, given reasons mentioned above

Comment: can I just do `useState(faker.name.firstName())` instead of `useState(() => faker.name.firstName())`?

Comment: I don't believe so, because then that argument to `useState` will **also** get run every render. And I'm not familiar with faker, but basically you don't want that function to run every render, you want it to run once on mount, and never again. And that's what the function argument does

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how `useEffect` works.
you have set `name` in `useEffect` array dependency. So everytime the component renders name changes, as name changes your component renders again and goes into infinity loop. So you leave empty array:

```
const [name, setName] = useState("");
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setName(faker.name.firstName());
      },[]);
    
    return <div>{name}</div>
```

Comment: react is not defined? https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-tfy7cz?file=App.tsx

Comment: ah my bad. Please recheck my code

Answer (score 0):

You have a `useEffect` that runs every time `name` changes.

When it runs, you're setting `name` to a new value.

This changes `name` and triggers the `useEffect` again.

When it runs, you're setting `name` to a new value.

This changes `name` and triggers the `useEffect` again.

And so on...